# How to download RAW files from A7 API?

Tags: api, camera, sony

I am working on a simple desktop tethering app for my A7 using the Wi Fi based JSON API.

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

All works well except I cannot download the RAW files. I can tweak things to get full size JPG file which seems to be served from the file system on the camera. for example the following URL seems to address the JPG from SD card.

http://myA7camera.info:8080/postview/memory/1000/DCIM/100MSDCF/DSC01353.JPG

This URL is coming back from `actTakePciture` call (I had to give the camera real like URL to satisfy stackoverflow posting requirements. In reality it is the camera IP addresss there). However although the camera is set to deliver `RAW+JPEG` and `RAW` file indeed is written to the card, the file is not accessible to download. I tried changing the extension.

I tried also plugging the camera into USB while working through API to be able to detect new files via filesystem monitoring and download them while controlling the camera via Wifi - no luck - USB connection terminates the Remote Camera Control App.

As well I cannot set the camera into RAW only mode while in the Remote Control App.

I browsed the "guide" and "accessControl" API facets but these do not seem to yield file download locations....

Any clues or ideas how to get my hands on the RAW files? Would be great to have tethered shooting via Wifi and Lightroom, no?

Comment: I have some more limitations. I was abel to unlock the API following advice on some other forums and have access to the full set of functions but: White balance only has color temperature, no control on Tint is possible. On A7 it is not possible to set the shooting mode P,A,S,M. I also did not find metering mode APIs - spot, center weight, evaluative etc.

Would be nice if the API allows to build full tethering app.

Comment: One more thing - the battery level is not in the API.

Comment: Great question! Did you ever find a solution to access the RAW files?

Comment: Not really. I tried many things but no luck over WiFi. 

There is chance to use USB tethering and then the camera would push the RAW file through after taking a picture. 

In the other USB modes you can browse the files on the SD card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing v4 of Smart Remote Control on A7ii I can now list the contents of SD Card and download RAW files and image previews. The sequence is roughly

1 move camera to recording mode (API does not work before this)

```
POST http://192.168.122.1:8080/sony/camera
{ "method": "startRecMode",
"params": [],
"id" : 1,
"version" : "1.0"}
```

2 move camera to contents transfer

```
POST http://192.168.122.1:8080/sony/camera
{ "method": "setCameraFunction",
"params": ["Contents Transfer"],
"id" : 1,
"version" : "1.0"}
```

3 list the images

```
http://192.168.122.1:8080/sony/avContent
{"method": "getContentList",
"params": [{
"uri": "storage:memoryCard1",
"stIdx": 0,
"cnt": 500,
"view": "flat",
"sort": ""}],
"id": 1,
"version": "1.3"}
```

There is new Camera Remote SDK v2.20

Comment: According to https://www.playmemoriescameraapps.com/portal/usbspec.php?eid=IS9104-NPIA09014_00-F00002 this does not work on the A7 or A7R, hopefully sony will add this feature in the future.

Comment: I'm getting the URL's for the content, but even after decoding them, I'm getting 500 errors with the GET request. They seem really strangely formatted. Any ideas?

URL: http://192.168.122.1:8080/contentstransfer/thumb/index://1000/00000001-default/00000043-00000AF0_67_1_1000

Comment: I'm getting the same problem - 500 (from URL such as http://192.168.122.1:8080/contentstransfer/orgjpeg/index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000001-default%2F00000001-00000925_1_1_1000) - were you able to find a way to overcome it?