# How to get the uncompressed pictures via SONY Camera Remote API(A5000)?

Tags: api, sony

By sending request to Camera(A5000), we can control it to take pictures and send back to my client. After decoding, we get a compressed pictures. Is there any solution to get the uncompressed one?
BTW,I also checked the API list, the function "transferring images" is unavailable on A5000.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

hmm... the picture you receive should not be compressed. Are  you able to plug in your usb and get an uncompressed picture? Try using the "setPostviewImageSize" parameter

```
{ 
method: 'setPostviewImageSize',  
id: 1,  
params: [ 'Original' ], version: '1.0' 
}
```

Here are the options:

- Original
- 2M
- MP4
- XAVC S
- XAVC S 4K

You could also try using the "setStillSize" parameter.

```
{
"method": "setStillSize",
"params": ["4:3","5M"],
"id": 1,
"version": "1.0"
}
```

Here are the options:

- "20M"
- "18M"
- "17M"
- "13M"
- "8.3M"
- "7.5M"
- "5M"
- "4.2M"
- "3.7M"
- "2.1M"

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I have compared the file size by connecting camera with usb. The file got by Remote API, is smaller than the source one, for example if the source one is 4.5m, the Remote one is about 1.6m. One more question,How to set the still size parameter to get a full-size pictures?

Comment: Bad news, A5000 don't support the setstill function from the API description. Any other solution?

Comment: hmm.. That is strange. As far as I can tell this should be supported on your camera. How did you find out that setStillSize was not supported? Do you get an error message with this text? Also can you paste in the data you are sending to the camera both for taking and receiving the picture as well as what you are sending for setStillSize. Maybe that can help me to better figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Following are the test results: 

Request:  {"id":21,"method":"getCameraFunction","version":"1.0","params":[]}
Response: {"id":21,"error":[1,"Not Available Now"]}

Request: {"id":23,"method":"setCameraFunction","version":"1.0","params":["Contents Transfer"]}
Response: {"id":23,"error":[1,"Not Available Now"]}

Request: {"id":25,"method":"setStillSize","version":"1.0","params":["4:3","5M"]}
Response: {"id":25,"error":[12,"setStillSize"]}

Comment: ok I see. Thanks for the post. It seems that the problem may be related specifcally to your camera. In the documentation there is this note: "*6: The setting in still mode is not available to cameras which have a hardware mode dial." Let me check with the team here to see if there is something else I can have you try

Comment: Oh actually, one more thing. Can you post here the JSON request you are using to take the picture as well as the response. That may also help me to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Maybe I should put the system version as following:                        
Using drivers OS-X-MSC, libusb-MTP
Looking for Sony devices

Querying MTP device
Sony Corporation ILCE-5000 is a camera in MTP mode

Model:              ILCE-5000
Product code:       0032826570
Serial number:      05329786
Firmware version:   1.10
Lens:               Model 0x12a08019 (Firmware 1.09)

Comment: Request: {"id":38,"method":"actTakePicture","version":"1.0","params":[]} 
   Response:{"id":38,"result":[["http:\/\/192.168.122.1:8080\/postview\/pict20171126_202521_0.JPG"]]}

Comment: Thanks for the code update! I am checking now to see what may be wrong.

Comment: ok thanks for your patience. I have found out that you can use the "setPostViewImageSize" option to change the image size. Here is an example request. : { method: 'setPostviewImageSize',  id: 1,  params: [ 'Original' ], version: '1.0' }. I have updated my answer to reflect this change

Comment: Great. It works. And one more question, it seems the pic file on the camera is smaller than the one got from remote app. It is a little strange, I thought camera would keep the original one.

Comment: it is probably because you are using the "setPostviewImageSize" parameter now. What option are you using to set the size? If you need the saved image size to be bigger you should be able to use "setStillSize" as mentioned above.

Comment: I set "postviewimagesize" as "original". I will try the stillsize settting, however, it is not a big problem. Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: One problem I am still not very sure. In the API guide of Feburary 2017, it says the A5000 doesn't support the function "setCameraFunction" and other functions of service "avContents". But if I don't misunderstand,the camera can call these service in fact?

Comment: If your camera does not support services that you call it should respond with an error message. Are you saying that these functions are working for you?

Comment: hi, Rober. I expect to continue the above question, I set the postviewsize as "Original" via remove api. In fact, the file size I got is different from the still picture when checking with the storage. The file size of postview is about 700k, otherwise the still size is 3.4M. So the question is, can I get the pic of "real original size"?

Comment: Actually you may be able to use getContentList this should give you a full list of all items on your device with download urls.

Answer (score 0):

I  do not think A5000 support download APIs. There is only preview available i.e. the small somewhat low quality files.

Here is link to how you do the download on newer models

[How to download RAW files from A7 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619743/how-to-download-raw-files-from-a7-api/33451375#33451375)